# Chunk file upload with PUT method is failing due to incorrect Content-Length auto calculation

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am using "HTTP Request" with PUT method for chunk file upload at sFiles {Salesforce share point}. (OS - Windows 10). FileToBeUploaded.pdf is the main file

$ ls -lrt File*

-rw-r--r-- 1 vikram 197121 12065018 Aug 23 15:51 FileToBeUploaded.pdf

-rw-r--r-- 1 vikram 197121  5773562 Aug 23 15:53 FileToBeUploaded_Chunks.pdf.ab

-rw-r--r-- 1 vikram 197121  6291456 Aug 23 15:53 FileToBeUploaded_Chunks.pdf.aa

For Chunk Upload

1. We have to divide a file to into equal parts and save it somewhere and upload each of them separately on the same URL that you get after creating a session.
2. Content-Length must be the total numbers of bytes of the file that you are uploading in all upload requests of fragments.
3. Content-Range will be like: 0-{fragmentLength-1}/{totalNumberOfBytesOfFile}(same as content-length) and from next fragment the Content-Range will be {uploadedBytes}-{uploadedBytes+nextSetOfBytes-1}/{totalNumberOfBytesOfFile}

To follow this we should have valid Content-Length & Content-Range passed in the request header.

ISSUE: But Jmeter [HTTP Request - HTTPClient4] is calculating content-length automatically and not taking the content-length defined in header manager. For chuck file uploads size in bytes should be accurately set for Content-Length & Content-Range . But Jmeter each time taking a new content-length as per it's auto calculation.
Client Side Error: [HTTP 400]
{"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"The Content-Range header length does not match the provided number of bytes."}}

I searched on all articles on the internet but could not found any resolution to control/override/hardcode Content-Length in request header.
This issue must be there for all share point websites which are using PUT method for chunk file upload. [Like Google Drive etc.]

Expected resolution: Way to control/override/hardcode/Configure Content-Length in "HTTP Request".

Please help on resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Google Drive documentation on resumable uploads](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#uploading):

> 1. Create a PUT request to the resumable session URI.
> 2. Add the file's data to the **request body.**
> 3. Add a Content-Length HTTP header, set to the number of bytes in the file.
> 4. Send the request. If the upload request is interrupted, or if you receive a 5xx response, follow the procedure in Resume an interrupted upload.

So if you're using "Files Upload" tab of the HTTP Request sampler it will send the file in full, you either need to point it to individual chunks or switch to the "Body Data" tab

You might also be interested in [building and sending your HTTP Requests using JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-http-request)

Comment: Sorry, it's not helping

Content-Range: 0-{${Content_Length_Of_Frist_Chunk}-1}/${Content_Length_Of_Full_File}

Jmeter [HTTP Request] is dynamically calculating and sending the content-length while initializing the request and overriding the Content-Length provided by me in Header Manager. Each time content-length is separate for the same request That's why I am not able to calculate Content-Range header which is dependent on Content-Length. 

If somebody can help with the code for calculating and saving content length using beanshell or JSR223 preprocessor can resolve the issue.